# How to type Tamil font in text box and save it in MySql

Tags: mysql, tamil

Im developing a small web application in PHP. I want, user or admin to type tamil language in text box or textarea and save it in MySql. Please give me some easiest method to do so.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Set MySql field collation to "utf8_general_ci"

Answer (score 0):

Vinoth, to allow a user to type in tamil on your website you might want to take a look at the *tamilsg api*

Usage: Copy & paste the following anywhere in the body tag of your php website and replace textareaid with the appropriate textarea id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var poplo =new Array("textareaid");
ENABLED_TIWEB = "http://api.tamilsg.com/data/lookuptable.js";
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.src = "http://api.tamilsg.com/hplus.js";
document.documentElement.appendChild(fileref);
</script>
```