# How to type tamil fonts in text boxes of a form field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tamil

I have a form field with **multiple text box**. I want to give input to the textbox in **Tamil font** for some textbox only for example 5 textbox out of 10 textbox in the one form.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377650/how-to-type-tamil-font-in-text-box-and-save-it-in-mysql) has code for **single text box** only. Can you help me to give input to multiple textbox by Tamil font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure what you mean. But i think you want to enable tamil unicode conversion on your textbox. There is script you can use.

[How to enable unicode Tamil conversion in your web pages](http://www.higopi.com/ucedit/reuse.html)

Comment: Thanks so much sir, they are giving complete source code in this URL: 1.http://www.higopi.com/script/ucedit/common.js
2.http://www.higopi.com/script/ucedit/tamil.js